# Symfony2 : PHPUnit How to use 'OR' condition in an assertion?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

Using Symfony2 with PHPUnit, how can I use a OR condition in an assertion?

In my case a client request can return codes `200` OR `302`, but the `assertEquals` expect only one possibility. Is there any way to throw an exception is the code is not `200` AND `302`?

```
private function check($method, $url, $code)
{
    echo "Expected code [".$code."] => URL ".$url."\n";
    $this->client->request($method, $url);
    $this->assertEquals($code, $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());        
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `assertContains` https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertContains

```
private function check($method, $url, $code)
{
    echo "Expected code [".$code."] => URL ".$url."\n";
    $this->client->request($method, $url);
    $this->assertContains($this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), array(200,302));        
}
```

Comment: Liked the idea. Cheers